# Different error messages under "Mandatory script verify flag failed."

Tags: transactions, script, transaction-verification, verification

I've been playing with raw transactions and signed transaction and I've noticed that the error "Mandatory script verify flag failed" comes in two variations.

1. script failed on OP_EQUALVERIFY OP
2. Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element.

Now, it appears that error number one is given whenever I try to send a transaction with the wrong TXID or index number. 
The second error can appear when I provide the wrong signature.

But aren't both errors just variant of a failure in executing the OP_EQUALVERIFY? At what step of the evaluation each error is thrown and what can we make out of it?

I'll highly appreciate any pointer you might have. I really struggle here to differentiate the two.

Answer (score 6):

> But aren't both errors just variant of a failure in executing the OP_EQUALVERIFY? At what step of the evaluation each error is thrown and what can we make out of it?

No, they're different errors. There are two rules that must be satisifed here:

1. The hash of the public key must match a certain value. (A failure here means you have the wrong key, or no key.)
2. The signature must be valid for the message and public key. (`OP_CHECKSIG` does not error immediately. It returns 0, which causes the script to fail.)

There are other script errors, too. See this list: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/script_error.cpp

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue while I was creating a raw transaction. I got the message: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed

```
(Script failed an OP_EQUALVERIFY operation)
```

I figure out that the issue behind is that I am signing with an erroneous key which wasn't related to the UTXO.
I had to backup the key tied to the UTXO address using dumpprivkey and sign with it.